# mysql restore database error in different version

Tags: mysql

i have Mysql DB dump file of MySql version 14.14 Distrib 5.1.34, for Win32 (ia32)

now i want to restore this dump file in Mysql version 14.12 Distrib 5.0.16, for Win32 (ia32)

it gives error like

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 278: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'USING BTREE,
  KEY `audit_trail_ibfk_1` (`USER_ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_audit' at line 8
```

When i restore this with same version it works..

Please Suggest.

Comment: c:\>mysql -h 192.168.100.11 -u root -p history < history.dump

Comment: I meant the query that was causing this error to trigger, not the command that was used to load the data. Anyways, I feel it's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution we can do same using compatible option along with mysqldump command like

```
mysqldump -u root --routines --compatible=mysql40 -p history < history.dump
```

where mysql40 is compatible with all version..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have hit a MySQL bug, see the [issue regarding `Using BTREE` when you downgrade your MySQL using mysqldump](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162)